# regex return false if string contains at least one questionmark

Tags: php, regex

I have a string where i want to detect if it contains at least one question mark. if it does return false. I tried to look for it but questiomark seems is a special character. How would you go about it?

thank you.

Comment: you specifically want a regex, or would any other logic work with you?

Comment: it needs to be regex. it's part of custom validation in cakephp. theoretically, it could be done with strpos but then I would have to implement an extra function for that.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to escape the ? in your regex.  `preg_match('/\?/','A string?',$matches)` will return a match for ? if one exists.

That said, you could just use `strpos()` for this.  It would be faster since you don't really need a regex engine to find ?

Comment: actually i need to have it other way around.. return true if there is no question mark. return false if there is at least one question mark

Comment: preg_match returns an int corresponding to matches found, so you can just add ! to the if you use this in and you'll be set.

Answer (score 3):

No need for regex.

```
if (strpos($str, '?') !== false) { 
    return false;
}

// Shorter but always executes due to lack of a conditional structure
// May not be what you need if you're doing various other checks
return strpos($str, '?') === false;
```

But you're right, `?` is a special character in regex. It tells the regex engine to look for zero or one occurrence of something.

If you're involving a check for a question mark in a more complicated regex, then as [Paul Kehrer says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211606/regex-return-false-if-string-contains-at-least-one-questionmark/4211618#4211618) you simply escape it with a backslash.